# How can you sync/share files from one computer to another in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using 2 computers to code in VS Code, but I want to sync a specific file when I edit it in both computers. Do you have any extensions, or servers that allows it to sync?

I tried looking in Google, some said try FTP, and some said use "Settings Sync". (I installed Settings Sync, but I don't really know if it can sync my files.)

Comment: How about using some source control like git. Push your code from one and pull your code from another and vice versa ?

Answer (score 3):

**Option 1**
Use [vscode remote development](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/remote-overview).
Select main machine which would host all the files and use SSH to access the files from the other machine.

**Option 2**
[Rsync](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) is a standard linux tool which can be used.
Use can use [vscode rsync extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscode-ext.sync-rsync) for syncing the files from one machine into the other.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the closest experience to what you have in mind that you can get currently on VSCode is [Visual Studio Live Share](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2017/11/15/live-share). This is an official extensions suite that lets you share your screen with multiple hosts, it also shares most of your current VSCode editor features (like intellisense) and can be enabled with voice and text chats. I would also suggest to set up a [git repository](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Getting-a-Git-Repository) for the files you are going to work with, so that hard copies of all your files will be avaialble to all your users.

Answer (score 0):

As of mid 2022 there is also the option to use the build-in "cloud changes" feature. This stores uncommitted changes to the cloud, using your logged in account and allows you to retrieve them on another machine.

To use it:

1. Enable the feature on both machines by selecting “Cloud Changes: Turn on Cloud Changes” from the Command Palette Command + Shift + P (macOS) / Ctrl + Shift + P (Windows/Linux). Alternatively, enable it under accounts settings UI.
2. Run “Cloud Changes: Store Working Changes in Cloud” from Command Palette on the first machine.
3. Run “Cloud Changes: Resume Latest Changes from Cloud” from Command Palette on the second machine.

I use this regularly myself when I'm working on two amchines and don't want to commit an interim state to github.

(Thanks to [pawelgrzybek](https://pawelgrzybek.com/use-cloud-changes-in-vs-code-to-sync-uncommitted-edits-between-two-computers/) for copy-pastable instructions.

Answer (score -1):

if your doing web development i'd rather just upload the code, to the web and download it to the all the pc's.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).